# Properties does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to store some strings in the Settings file of my project. However, I am not able to access the Settings file to store the strings.

I definitely have accessed Properties file in an earlier project without facing any problems to store values.

`Properties.Settings.Default.test = ...`
`MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.test = ...`

But here in the current project, I am constantly being driven mad by getting the `Properties does not exist in the current context`
Is there any setting or something that has changed because of which `Properties` does not appear in Intellisense?

Comment: Can you check the code generation of your .settings file?

Comment: @Adriano: Settings.settings file Properties. Code generator: `SettingsSingleFileGenerator` and the settings.cs file is getting generated fine.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had this same problem occur when I had been copying and pasting code for plug-ins.  It turns out that I had accidentally left the namespace of the other project in place when I copied.  By changing the namespace back to the appropriate project, I was able to use the Properties.

Comment: An easy way to see all the namespaces in your project is to open the Class View in Visual Studio. Open a file in the old namespace and refactor the name.

Answer (score 22):

at compile-time, Visual Studio generates a c# class which allows access to user and application settings. the generated class is defined in the **default namespace** specified in the **project settings**.

- you may have to prefix any access to the Properties namespace with the default namespace defined in the project settings;
- or you may change the default namespace: go to project settings, application tab, and edit the default namespace of the project.

Comment: This totally fixed my issue, I just had to change the default namespace to match what was in the class i was consuming the code in.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer really helped me!  I had modified the namespace in the project and it was slightly different than it was in the class.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your project **has** a settings file by going to the project properties and clicking on the Settings tab. If there is no settings file, it will tell you so and provide you with the option to create one.

Comment: Yes, it has the settings file and the settings.cs file is getting generated fine. Checked the `Settings.settings` file Properties and the code generator is equal to `SettingsSingleFileGenerator`

Comment: And your project recognizes the settings file when you go to the project properties -> Settings?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can enter the strings manually here, but these are not accessible inside my MainWindow.xaml.cs code

Comment: Strange. Can you upload the project someplace so we can check it out?

Comment: This is what solved the problem for me! As soon as I created the settings file as you described, the "Properties" object came into scope. Thank you.

Comment: This did the trick after I apparently messed things up by having one of the resource files open in another tool when I tried to rebuild.  I also had to remove the resource files that were still shown and add them back again.

Comment: Though the link *Create or open application settings* recognized a `Settings.settings` file, the code only compiled after deleting that settings file, after which it is created beneath a "Properties" folder by clicking the link, making `Properties.Settings.Default` accessible.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error when I accidentally had the wrong namespace as the Default namespace in the project properties.

To choose the default namespace, right click the project in the Solution ExplorerProperties->Application tab->Default namespace and check that it matches the namespace of your .cs files:

```
[...]
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

    namespace Correct.Namespace //<-- should match Default namespace field
    {
        static class Program
        {
            [...]
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i have referenced a resource that has an Internal/Public access modifier. I have changed its access modifier to Public and the problem was gone.

Comment: This was my problem too, additionally I needed to declare the property variable outside the Property method before the set accessor recognized it.

Answer (score 4):

**First**, try to recreate your project from scratch, if it's your testing environment. This step will recreate default namespace properly. You may skip this step if you are confident with your namespace configurations.

**Second**, if you still get Properties unrecognize as in my example where im trying to get data from sqlCon.

```
string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.sqlCon;
```

[image]

go to **Project** -> **EventsandDelegates Properties** as shown in the picture below. Make sure to create default settings file.

[image]

**As soon as you create default settings under your Application settings**, in my case it's SQL connection variable. `Properties` error will go away.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. But the problem occured when I added a new setting to an already defined settings file (created a long time ago). **Somehow adding a setting to the settings file made Visual Studio change the setting's namespace to the project default namespace** (which had changed since the settings where modified last time).

So, because the settings access modifier was set to Internal, and the class trying to access the settings still where in the old previous namespace (still in the same project though), the settings became invisible from that class.

Answer (score 2):

Quickest Solution i can offer is to double click on your resources.resx file if it exists, than change the Access Modifier Property at the top of the window from Internal to Public, Rebuild, which should compile successfully, then switch it back to internal and rebuild again. Should be fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was referencing one project (A) from another (B). Both in the same solution.

- A has a public class (AClass) with a public static method. (AMethod)
- I wanted to Test the results of this AClass.AMethod(...)
- Visual Studio "colored" AClass in the call AClass.AMethod(...)
- and I could right-click AClass and "Go to Definition",

  - which took me either directly to the  source if I added referenced to the "Solution" project
  - Or to the DLL "outline" if I added reference to the DLL created by building Project "A"
- But when I tried to build project "B" I got the error "AClass does not exist in current context"
- It turns out Project B was targeting 4.5 and Project A was targeting 4.5.2
- This answer helped:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556365/1175496

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can see your setting in Settings.Designer.cs file. If not, try deleting and reentering the setting. For some reason, sometimes, the code auto generated by the tool does not include your setting. In that case, the setting wont be available in intellisense.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_

Answer (score 0):

Funny, but in my case, I had defined the `Properties` *in one project* in the solution and was trying to access *from another*.
Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

My issue with the "does not contain a definition for 'Properties'", was caused by adding a class to the namespace (JsonBreaker), with the same name as the namespace (ie `JsonBreaker.JsonBreaker`). Its notable that it was breaking compilation, as it seems some other folks are having a different experience.

```
namespace JsonBreaker {
  public class JsonBreaker {

     private readonly Options _opt = null;
...
```

I just changed the classname (and .cs filename) to `Breaker`, and my `JsonBreaker.Properties.Settings.Default["InteractiveMode"]` call started compiling again.

```
namespace JsonBreaker {
   public class Breaker {

     private readonly Options _opt = null;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when running my web project in Visual Studio 2019. After unsuccessfully trying some of the solutions here, I closed VS2019 and re-opened the project from VS2017. Now the Properties namespace is being recognised.

Answer (score 0):

My case:

- I added a new database in the Solution Explorer
- I tried:
  `string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.SlovickaSQLConnectionString;`

My error:

- I get:

  Properties does not exist in the current context

Here is why:

- I forget to add a new dataset in Data Sources panel.

This dataset has to be connected to the previously added database.

And now it works..