# Visual Studio 2017 file icon after saving file changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone know why every time I save changes to a file within Visual Studio 2017 it changes my file icon (see screenshot below)?

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the result of an extension I've installed or was rolled out within an update to Visual Studio.

I would really like to disable this, any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

This doesn't seem to be related to Git integration as the icons still change with source control features disabled (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the MEF Cache of VS2017, lemme know if it works

Comment: @DevEstacion Cleared the MEF cache and restarted VS, still the icons are changing.

Comment: See this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556365/604232](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556365/604232)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue for .NET Core solutions within Visual Studio 2017.

The developer community has already reported this issue, see [Solution Shows Missing File Icon](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80855/solution-shows-missing-file-icon.html?childToView=92853#comment-92853), which is currently "Under Investigation".

**Updated August 30, 2017**

The fix for this known issue is now currently marked as "Fixed - Pending Release".

**Updated September 15, 2017**

This issue has been fixed and is included within [version 15.4](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-Preview-relnotes) which is included in [Visual Studio 2017 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/). Downloaded and confirmed this is not longer an issue with the preview edition.

Answer (score 0):

If you made sure VS didn't throw any error, warning or info exception in its Error List regarding the modified file, it most likely is related to the Git integration this Visual Studio edition came with. It works like a file version controller software, showing visual icons like this one to show if the files were commited and if they were, if they are new or not and altered or not.

To disable source code control, go to Tools, Options, Source Code Control and select None. If nothing changes instantly, I recommend restarting VS and checking again.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue. I disabled source control integration and restarted VS, still the icons are changing. I updated the original question with a screenshot of your suggested changes.

Comment: Did you take a look at VS error list? Do it while viewing the said file and let me know in the comments. If no error is being thrown, try to add an empty HTML tag in a different file and save it, to see if the same happens again.