# SqlDependency messes up application properties

Tags: c#, .net, sqldependency

In C# windows forms application in main Form constructor I have the following code (updated to the actual code from the app):

```
SqlDependency.Stop(Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeHealthDB, Properties.Settings.Default.NotificationQueueName);
        IsUsingSqlDependency = SqlDependency.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeHealthDB, Properties.Settings.Default.NotificationQueueName);
```

SQL dependency works intermittently and quite often I am getting following error on the second statement:

> Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr   'System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Settings' and no extension method
>   'Settings' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

As you can see the first statement refers to exactly the same settings values and it doesn't fail.

On occasions when this part works the application is able to catch database changes and do what I want it to do, but it may give an error on application exit (on Form Closing event) where I use the same exactly statement (as first one) to stop dependency as above. The debugger doesn't provide any useful information, no stack information available. The error can be either SqlException or the same as above.

I just ran my application 6 times (in debugger) - without changing anything and without doing anything within the application - just open main form and close main form. First two times I got the error on SqlSDependency.Start, then next 4 times it ran just fine.

Using VS 2013 Professional, .NET 4.5, C#. Building on Win 7 x64 but generated code is for x32 bit systems.

I thought that using dependency was a great idea because users wanted to see changes made by other users without manually refreshing data but I am struggling.

Comment: The error message you are getting is a compiler error.  There is no way you were able to run your code, as posted, 6 times with different results, if you saw that error.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the exception when it occurs?

Comment: Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46d7aef0-bdfe-4b7e-b74c-4b1d067c4000/why-does-my-vsto-cnet-project-not-let-me-examine-application-settings-at-runtime?forum=vsto help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properties does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665335/properties-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Bradley, if it were compiler error I wouldn't be able to run it, right? But it was running intermittently. I ran it 6 more times and so far o good, no errors. I will be posting updates if this happens again.

Comment: mjwills, thank you for two links. I think this may be it! I updated my code throughout the project to include my project namespace like that: EmployeeHealth.Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeHealthDB instead of Properties.Settings.Default.EmployeeHealthDB.

Answer (score 0):

Adding application namespace as in the linked article provided by mjwills resolved my issue.

[Properties does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665335/properties-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)